# Why I get error module not available in JSFiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I declare this module:

```
 angular.module('dashboard', [])
    .controller('dashboardController', ['$scope',
            function ($scope) {
                $scope.data = "555";
            }]);
```

And here is view:

```
<div ng-app="dashboard" data-role="page" id="layersProperty" data-add-back-btn="true" >
    <div ng-controller="dashboardController">
            {{data}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jo743mp0/1/).

In console I get this error:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'dashboard' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Any idea why I get error above?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qekezayipa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Very strange indeed. Your exact same code, loading angular.js from the same location, works fine in plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NHqBPkItZiNsqhJ8beG7?p=preview

Comment: On the JSFiddle, change the Load Type of the javascript to be `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>` instead of `onLoad`. It's a JSFiddle thing and how it works with Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No issue with your code, since you are adding external scripts you just need to change

**`Javascript settings -> Load type -> Wrap in <Head>`**
[image]

Comment: Good find. Such an easy and strange setting to miss!

Comment: Wow, this little thing drove me crazy

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the javascript Load Type you have set on JSFiddle. When you use `onLoad`, JSFiddle will wrap your javascript in a `$(window).load(function (){});` block. This means the `angular.module()` code that registers your Angular app will not run until after the DOM has been processed. So Angular tries to find a `dashboard` module that has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Basically  your code looks good and by the way its working check it [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uopnLOvsjcfmLX4Tyvxq?p=preview) .

check your code (did you include angular?) or just post your full code.

code in Plnkr :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="dashboard" ng-controller="dashboardController">
    {{ data }}
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module('dashboard', [])
      .controller('dashboardController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.data = "555";
        }
      ]);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```